# XAML GridView design time data from json

Tags: c#, json, wpf, xaml, gridview

How easy bind design time data to grid view?

I bind json to Grid.TextBlock but Grid.GridView.DataTemplate not show data

**Xaml**

```xml
<Page
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=/SampleData/sampledata.json}"
>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel 
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <GridView 
        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}"
        >
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"></WrapGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Width="50" Height="50" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

**Json**

```
{
    "Name": "Root Name",
    "ListItems": [
        { "Name": "Title 1" },
        { "Name": "Title 2" },
        { "Name": "Title 3" }
    ]
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

this is an advice more than an answer. JSON design data seems to be supported only by Windows 8.1 projects.
I suggest another solution, using a mock class that provide the properties you need. In your case you could create a **SampleData** class with the **ListItems** property:

```
public class ListItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SampleData
{
    //Parameterless constructor needed!
    public SampleData()
    {
        ListItems = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>();
        ListItems.Add(new ListItem { Name = "foo" });
        ListItems.Add(new ListItem { Name = "bar" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ListItem> ListItems { get; set; }
}
```

The **SampleData** class needs to have a parameterless constructor!

In the XAML file just add the design-time datacontext (the **local** tag referr to the SampleData class assembly;

```
...
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfDesignDataTest"
...

<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:SampleData, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
```